# XCode 4.1 with lion

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion

I recently updated my Snow Leopard to Lion and today, I went to open XCode and it gave me an error saying that the XCode I had wasn't compatible with Lion, or something like that.

Did some research, and ended up installing XCode 4.1 from the Mac App Store.

Well, that was about 3 hours ago, and I'm installing and it says "Updating Files" and the loading bar is almost to the very end of the line. It's been this way for about an hour. Should I quit and restart? Should I just wait? Why is it taking so painstakingly long?

[image]

Comment: You can kill the install and use the old perl clean up script in /Developer/Library and then try again. If you open the package contents, the familiar installers are there for you to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I had was that there was still an iTunes process running.
I could solve this by stopping the 'iTunes helper' process.
After stopping that process the installation of XCode continued and installed quickly.

Comment: I don't see an iTunes process running. Where would I see that? I checked the Activity Monitor and couldn't find anything related to iTunes.

Comment: You can check that in the Activity Monitor. In my case there is always a process running called 'iTunes helper' even if iTunes is stopped. Stopping that process solved the issue for me. Check that to be sure.

Comment: I did find it. I had to change the filter to "All Processes." I stopped iTunes Helper but it didn't progress. I ended up redoing it completely. Hope it works this time.

Comment: That's the same what I did, stop iTunes, stop the helper process and install again. Hope that helps!

Comment: I redid it this time and quit the iTunes Helper from the start. But it's still frozen at that same spot as the picture above. It's been there a while now.

Comment: Then I should try a complete reinstall. Start by removing Xcode with the command sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all (in most cases the full path to <Xcode> is /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools). Make sure you restart your Mac after removing Xcode completely. Then do a fresh install.

Comment: Macintosh-11:~ myname$ <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
-bash: Xcode: No such file or directory

Comment: replace <Xcode> with the full path to Xcode. In most cases the full path is /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as @Mark, but I still had to force quit the installer, and try again. The second time through it installed fine.

Comment: @reising1 -- I just tried it again.  It still took > 30 minutes, but it installed correctly.

Comment: ugh. stuck at that same spot again :(

Comment: @reising1 -- sorry to hear that.  You could try removing your old Xcode build from Applications and try again (I know...).  I would at least keep a backup of the old Xcode App.